# Relate two tables by one matching key in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, inner-join, create-table

I'm pretty new to SQL and I know about `FOREIGN KEY`, but I can't think of a way to link two tables with each other by one key matching.

So, for example, there's a user with the "name" set as "John" and a post that has an "author" set as "John".

What query should i write to have SQL look through "users" table, find a match with post's author, and set a `FOREIGN KEY` to an id of that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a `users` and a `posts` table, where `posts` have a `user_id` `foreign key` referencing `users.id`, you can do something like this:

```
update posts
join users
on posts.author = users.name
set posts.user_id = users.id;
```

The problem you might face is that some names might be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

That's one-to-many relationship.

You would build the tables as follows:

```
create table users (
    user_id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50)
);

create table posts (
    post_id int primary key auto_increment,
    user_id int not null,
    content varchar(200),
    constraint fk_user_id foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

Then you can use the foreign key to join the tables:

```
select p.*, u.name as user_name
from posts p
inner join users u on u.user_id = p.user_id
```

Comment: I believe the asker was wondering about the way to update posts.user_id so it will have the correct users.id value, linked by name-author logical relation, see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, i have two JSON files filled with a bunch of users and posts. I was going to parse them into two separate tables and i thought the best way to relate them with each other would be adding a FOREIGN KEY after seeding both tables and making a certain JOIN query with filters set. The only matching key they both have is the name.